Create a folder with sub-folder structure with specific names and dates
Hi I'm looking for a little help here to create a folder structure using PowerShell.
Pointing at a root folder [Yearly Structure Folder], im looking for the following structure within this folder.
The first layer of subfolders would be the months of the year prefixed wiith a number to keep them in order.
[01. January] through to [12. December]
Inside each of the month folders would have the same sub structure as follows.
[01. General], [02. Housekeep in], [03. Housekeep out], [04. Record], [05. Timesheet]
The dates of the month would be in each of the above folders and named 01.01.2024, 02.01.2024 (dd-MM-yyyy) and so forth with the amount of days in each month.
[01.01.2024] through to [31.01.2024] with the correct dates within that month
Then within each of the single date folders would have these folders in each one.
[01. Request], [02. Copies], [03. Report], [04. Recom], [05. Checks], [06. Forms]
I have attached an image of the general structure for the one month. I have also been looking at these posts although they are similar to what I want, When I edit them and run, I get errors and not sure how to combine them.
Creating a sub-folder structure
create a folder structure with name and date +7 days
Appreciate anyone have a bit time to help me get started with this :)
I have also been looking at these posts although they are similar to what I want, When I edit them and run, I get errors and not sure how to combine them.
Creating a sub-folder structure
create a folder structure with name and date +7 days
Screenshot
This is what I have so far, although I dont need to exclude dates and dont need the single dates prefixed with a number.
   {New-Item -Path "C:\Yearly Structure Folder" -Type Directory

$folders = ("01. General", "02. Housekeep in", "03. Housekeep out", "04. Record", "05. Timesheet" )
$folders | ForEach { New-Item -Path "C:\Yearly Structure Folder" -Name $_ -Type Directory }


$startDate = [datetime]'01-01-2024'
$endDate = $startDate.AddMonths(12)
$startWeek = 1
$folderPath = "C:\Yearly Structure Folder\01. General"
$datesToExclude = @(
      # This will Exclude 30 of December 2021
) | ForEach-Object {$_ -as [datetime]}

do
{
if($startDate -notin $datesToExclude)
{
$folderName = "{0} {1}" -f $startWeek, $startDate.ToString('dd.MM.yyyy')
$newFolderPath = Join-Path $folderPath -ChildPath $folderName
New-Item $newFolderPath -ItemType Directory
}

$startDate = $startDate.AddDays(1)
$startWeek++

}until($startDate -ge $endDate)


The only person who can "get started" on this is you. If you've run into errors you don't understand and need help troubleshooting: post the exact commands you ran and the related error messages in full - we can't see your screen :)

You can start by sharing the errors: learning from them means avoiding repeating them. Also makes easier for us to help.

Welcome to SO, user24911908. SO is not a free, bespoke programming service. Show us the code you are trying to make work.

Sorry lads, I have edited the OP

You need to use Nested Loops
Here the smallest example I managed to make
I have no doubt there is some more efficient way, perhaps with hashtables
# replace the value with whatever you need
$Path = '.\'

$MonthSubDirectoryNameList = '01. General', '02. Housekeep in', '03. Housekeep out', '04. Record', '05. Timesheet'
$DaySubDirectoryNameList = '01. Request', '02. Copies', '03. Report', '04. Recom', '05. Checks', '06. Forms'


# set the year you want.
$Year = 2024

# set the starting date to january 1
$Date=Get-Date -Year $year -Month 1 -Day 1



# Set culture for the name of the Month.
# Invariant Culture FTW if you do not need some specific language
$Culture = [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture

# for each day starting from 1 of January
# as long the Year is equal to $Year
# do stuff
# adding 1 day at the end of each loop
for ($Date; $date.year -eq $Year; $Date = $Date.AddDays(1)) {

    foreach ($MonthSub in $MonthSubDirectoryNameList) {
        foreach ($DaySub in $DaySubDirectoryNameList) { 
            #$DayDirectory = Join-Path -Path $Year -ChildPath $Date.ToString('MM. MMMM', $Culture) -AdditionalChildPath $MonthSub, $Date.ToString('dd.MM.yyyy'), $DaySub
            $DayDirectory = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($year, $Date.ToString('MM. MMMM', $Culture) , $MonthSub, $Date.ToString('dd.MM.yyyy'), $DaySub)
            # assigned to $null to hide the output.
            $Null = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $PAth -Name $DayDirectory -Force
        }
        
    }
    
}


I changed the path but getting this error.
[`Join-Path : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AdditionalChildPath'.
At line:28 char:99

... ath $Date.ToString('MM. MMMM', $Culture) -AdditionalChildPath $MonthS ...

                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand`]




my bad, I keep forgetting to ask people what version of powershell they are using.
I updated the code to use $DayDirectory = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($year, $Date.ToString('MM. MMMM', $Culture) , $MonthSub, $Date.ToString('dd.MM.yyyy'), $DaySub) which works for both 5.1 and 7+

Nice one my friend. Just need to figure out how to implement this into Sharepoint now :/

Ah, I just noticed the 01. January folders would also need the year to it, example 01. January 2024 and without the top folder being the year. MY BAD

Those kind of fix you can easily do yourself. Check Teh Docs for how to format time in strings
